# Every subsequence of $\mathbb{N}_O$ is monotone increasing

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

Just wanted to double check this elementary analysis proof -- let me know if you have any thoughts as to how it might be improved. I'm particularly interested in thoughts around the $\mathbb{N}_O$ notation used to describe the sequence $\{1, 2, 3, ... \}$ and suggestions for more standard alternatives.

**Theorem**
Every subsequence of $\mathbb{N}_O$ is monotone increasing

**Proof**

Suppose there exists a subsequence of $\mathbb{N_O}$ that is not monotone increasing, say $B_n$. Then there exists some $x_n \in B_n$ such that $x_n \geq x_{n + \eta}$ for some $\eta > 0$. Since $B_n$ inherits the index mapping of $\mathbb{N}_O$ and the index mapping of $\mathbb{N}_O$ is the identity mapping, we have $$n + \eta \geq n \leftrightarrow \eta \geq 0$$

But $\eta > 0$. This contradicts our assumption that there exists such a subsequence of $\mathbb{N}_O$. Then every subsequence of $\mathbb{N}_O$ is monotone increasing.

Comment: Actually, every subsequence of a monotone sequence $(x_n)$ has the same monotony as $(x_n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, but you can make it a little more simple by picking sensible notation and avoiding the proof by contradiction:

First, I'm not a fan of the notation, because it doesn't let you refer to elements of the sequence in a nice way. Instead, I'll denote your base sequence as $(x_n)$, so its $n$th term is just $x_n$.

And for the actual proof:

Let $(y_k) = (x_{n_k})$ be any subsequence of $(x_n)$. Then for any $k > l$, we have $n_k > n_l$, and so $y_k = x_{n_k} > x_{n_l} = y_l$, since $(x_n)$ is monotone increasing. Thus, $(y_k)$ is monotone increasing.